# I need help checking to see if the answer I got is correct answer

Tags: significant-figures

My professor says that the answer is 583.5g. I got 583.0330822g. She says to use her periodic table. Her periodic table says the mass of Ag: 107.87g, N: 14.01g, O: 16.00g, and S: 32.06g. Below is the problem. Did anyone get the same answer as my professor or mine or neither?
[image]

Comment: Please try to find a reasonable title. While being as concise as possible, it shall indicate, without ambiguity, the subject matter of the question in such a way as to distinguish it from that of other questions, without going into unnecessary detail.

Comment: @Evelyn we don't do homework for others.

Comment: Noticed that 1167/2 = 583.5

Answer (score 1):

In multiple choice questions, sometimes you have to use the *best* approximation. If one of the answers was 583.5 g and you were getting 583.0 g, chances are the first choice is correct ***in the mind*** of the question writer. It does not have to be the most accurate or factual answer (you have to choose from the given choices using **the given data**).

Your teacher cannot make a lame excuse that *her* periodic table must be used. In science there is no authority (his or her periodic table). The International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry should have the accurate mases. Download the IUPAC period table and and calculate once again using the masses given there. What do you get?

https://iupac.org/what-we-do/periodic-table-of-elements/

Comment: Whatever the calculation, finding a result with ten significant figures (583.0330822) is a non-sense when starting from data known with only 4 significant figures like 16.00 for  the oxygen atoms and 14.01 for the nitrogen atom.

Comment: @Maurice - I agree that 583.0330822 is nonsense, but the atomic mass of $\ce{AgS2}$ will have 5 significant figures using the data given since both the mass of silver and sulfur are given to the hundredths decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

**Your teacher is wrong. Your answer of "none of the above" was correct.**

> However the value of $\pu{583.0330822 g}$ is nonsense. There are way too many significant figures. The value should be rounded to 5 significant figures, or $\pu{583.03 g}$.

I disagree with user M. Farooq about the periodic table. My perception is that the teacher wanted all the students to use a particular periodic table (hers) to avoid rounding errors between all the students.

First since all the masses were given to the hundredths decimal place, the answer should have 5 significant figures.

$$\begin{align}
\text{molecular mass }\ce{AgNO3} &= 107.87 + 14.01 + 3\times16.00  \\
&=107.87 + 14.01 + 48.00 \\
&= 169.88 \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\text{molecular mass }\ce{Ag2S} &= 2\times107.87 + 32.06  \\
&= 215.74 + 32.06 \\
&= 247.80 \\
\end{align}$$

> My calculator shows 247.8 for $\ce{Ag2S}$, but my calculator doesn't understand significant figures. The answer must be 247.80.

$$\begin{align}
\text{mass }\ce{Ag2S} &= \dfrac{799.40}{169.88}\times\dfrac{1}{2}\times247.80 \\
&= 583.03308217565340240169531433953 \\
&\ce{->[Round to 5]} 583.03\\
\end{align}$$

Now the touchy part with such problems is the possibility of rounding errors in intermediate calculations. However the molecular masses are correct to the hundredths place. Also the final calculation was done in one overall calculation so there was no intermediate step. Thus the answer of "none of the above" is correct.

Now if I had calculated the moles of $\ce{Ag2S}$ as a separate step, then I'd used two extra digits in the intermediate calculation to try and avoid rounding errors. Thus:

moles $\ce{Ag2S} = \dfrac{799.40}{169.88}\times\dfrac{1}{2} = 2.352837$

mass $\ce{Ag2S} = 2.352837 \times 247.80 = 583.0330086 \ce{->[round to 5]} 583.03$

I fiddled around a bit with the calculations and I can't determine how the teacher calculated the 583.5 g answer. It seems to obviously be a rounding error, but I don't know how to reconstruct the steps in the teacher's calculation.

Comment: think I can point to the calculation error finally. $$\text{mass }\ce{Ag2S} = \dfrac{799.40}{169.88}\times\dfrac{1}{2}\times248(?) =583.5$$